# iOS 14 Cordova Chrome Socket Binding not working

Tags: ios, cordova, sockets

I have a cordova app that is trying to bind to a UDP multicast IP on my network.

I've included both bind requests in the code below. I only have 1 active at a time.

The problem is I need to bind to 239.250.250.250 but iOS throws this error:

ERROR: Unknown interface. Specify valid interface by name (e.g. "en1") or IP address.

```
chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(createInfo) {
  var _socketUdpId = createInfo.socketId;
  console.log(_socketUdpId);

  //THIS BINDS, BUT IT'S NOT THE IP I NEED
  chrome.sockets.udp.bind(_socketUdpId, "127.0.0.1", 9131, function(bindresult) {
    if (bindresult < 0) {
      console.log("Error binding socket.");
      return;
    }
    console.log("bind result 386 : ", bindresult);
  });

  //THIS DOES NOT BIND. BINDRESULT IS 2.
  chrome.sockets.udp.bind(_socketUdpId, "239.255.250.250", 9131, function(bindresult) {
    if (bindresult < 0) {
      console.log("Error binding socket.");
      return;
    }
    console.log("bind result: ", bindresult);
  });
```

Any ideas why 239.255.250.250 does not work? I've been stuck for a while on this and have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reverting to a previous cordova build and it was the socket was able to work. The code was the same, so it must have been an issue with a plugin or configuration.